# What replaced WearableListView.Adapter?

Tags: android, listview, wear-os

I just built an AndroidStudio projects, and am being told that the `WearableListView.Adapter` class is deprecated.

However, when I go to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/WearableListView.Adapter.html), it says nothing about being deprecated. I haven't been able to figure out what class should be used instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Introduced in Wear 2.0, you should use the `WearableRecyclerView` class as described in the [Curved Layout documentation](https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/features/wearable-recycler-view.html).

Comment: This worked great. Easy to swap in and out too. Thanks!